# Image Warping Python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, transform

I have the following two images:
[source Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMtYT.jpg)
[destination Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2L67d.jpg)

I want to warp the source image into the first (left) shape in the destination image using projective transformation, and to warp the source image into the second(right) shape in the destination image.
So what i've done is first of all find the interest points which are:

src_interest_pts=np.float32([[0, 0],[0, 640],[480,0],[480, 640]]) which are the corners of my image

Affine_interest_pts= np.float32([[41,215],[849,54],[602,458],[608,300]]) which are the corners of the right shape

Projective_interest_pts= np.float32([[195, 56],[494,158],[36, 183],[432, 498]])

and wrote the following code:

```
img = cv2.imread("Q3/Dylan.jpg")
frame=cv2.imread("Q3/frames.jpg")
rows,cols,ch = frame.shape

src_interest_pts = np.float32([[0, 0],[0, 640],[480,0],[480, 640]])
Affine_interest_pts = np.float32([[41,215],[849,54],[602,458],[608,300]])
Projective_interest_pts = np.float32([[195, 56],[494,158],[36, 183],[432, 498]])

M = cv2.getAffineTransform(src_interest_pts ,Affine_interest_pts)
Affinedst = cv2.warpAffine(img,M,(cols,rows))

M=cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src_interest_pts ,Projective_interest_pts)
Projectivedst=cv2.warpPerspective(img,M,(cols,rows))

dst=Affinedst+Projectivedst
plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img),plt.title('Input')
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(dst),plt.title('Output')
plt.show()
```

the result is that the getAffineTransform returns an error because there must be 3 interest points from source to destination but in my case there are 4.

after deleting the code of the affine we get:

```
   src_interest_pts = np.float32([[0, 0],[0, 640],[480,0],[480, 640]])
   Projective_interest_pts = np.float32([[195, 56],[494,158],[36, 183],[432, 498]])
   M=cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src_interest_pts ,Projective_interest_pts)
   Projectivedst=cv2.warpPerspective(img,M,(cols,rows))
   plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(frame),plt.title('The frame')
   plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(Projectivedst),plt.title('Warped')
   plt.show()
```

and here is the output image that I'm getting:
[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xVwr.jpg)

my question is:

How do i get the desired output?

Maybe my problem is in the interest points?

Why is the getAffineTransform isn't working for the second(right) shape? For this warping i have to warp using affine transformation only.

## Edit:

I changed the points to be :

```
pts1 = np.float32([[0, 0],[640, 0],[0,480],[640, 480]])
# ptsAffine = np.float32([[215,41],[54,849],[458,602],[300,608]])
ptsProjective = np.float32([[55, 195],[158,494],[183, 36],[498, 432]])
```

as @fmw42 noted in his comment I've been switching between the indices (what in x should be in y and the opposite)
but still I'm getting this output I guess it's hard for me to figure out the right points.
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjQrk.jpg)

Comment: Please post the exact error message and where in your code it occurs. I think the issue is you have defined points as y,x and they need to be defined as x,y in your np.float32 arrays. Your input is width=640 and height=480, but you specify the second point as 0,640. That would be x=0, y=640. But it should be x=640 and y=0, so 640,0. Looking at your Affine points, the first you list is 41,215. But that is not any where near the right side quadrilateral. It is close to the left quadrilateral, but not good in my opinion, nor is 215,41. So your output points are not measured accurately

Comment: Your other issue is that you need to use estimateAffine2D in place of getAffineTransform

Comment: Thanks for the answers I guess I haven't been using the right points!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comments, you have several issues. Your points are not defined correctly and you need to use estimateAffine2D in place of getAffineTransform.  This works for me in Python/OpenCV.

Input:

[image]

Output Frame:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread("Dylan.jpg")
frame=cv2.imread("frames.jpg")
rows,cols,ch = frame.shape

# x,y points are cw from top left
src_interest_pts = np.float32([[0,0],[640,0],[640,480],[0,480]])
Affine_interest_pts = np.float32([[551,224],[843,67],[903,301],[608,455]])
Projective_interest_pts = np.float32([[195,56],[494,158],[432,498],[36,183]])

M = cv2.estimateAffine2D(src_interest_pts ,Affine_interest_pts)[0]
Affinedst = cv2.warpAffine(img,M,(cols,rows))

M=cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src_interest_pts ,Projective_interest_pts)
Projectivedst=cv2.warpPerspective(img,M,(cols,rows))

dst=Affinedst+Projectivedst
plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img),plt.title('Input')
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(dst),plt.title('Output')
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Opencv Affine transform function requires three source and destination point to get affine 2x3 matrix. You can also find a approximate affine transform for the overdetermined set of equations. Try this function to generate affine transformation matrix for the given problem

```
def affine(x, y):
    b = np.array([y[0][0], y[0][1], y[1][0], y[1][1], y[2][0], y[2][1], y[3][0], y[3][1]])
    A = np.array([[x[0][0], x[0][1], 1, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, x[0][0], x[0][1], 1],
    [x[1][0], x[1][1], 1, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, x[1][0], x[1][1], 1],
    [x[2][0], x[2][1], 1, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, x[2][0], x[2][1], 1],
    [x[3][0], x[3][1], 1, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, x[3][0], x[3][1], 1]])

    coef = np.linalg.inv(A.T @ A) @ A.T @ b
    M = np.array([[coef[0], coef[1], coef[2]],[coef[3], coef[4], coef[5]]], dtype=np.float64)
    return M
```

Try to call it like this:

```
rows,cols,ch = frame.shape

src_interest_pts = np.float32([[0, 0],[640,0],[640,480], [0,480]])
Affine_interest_pts = np.float32([[548,215],[849,54],[908,300],[602,458]])
Projective_interest_pts = np.float32([[195, 56],[494,158],[432, 498],[36, 183]])

M = affine(src_interest_pts, Affine_interest_pts)
Affinedst = cv2.warpAffine(img,M,(cols,rows))

M=cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src_interest_pts ,Projective_interest_pts)
Projectivedst=cv2.warpPerspective(img,M,(cols,rows))

dst=Affinedst+Projectivedst
    
    plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img),plt.title('Input')
    plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(dst),plt.title('Output')
    plt.show()
```

You would get a output like this. I hope this solves your problem.
[image]